# Random record from mysql database with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, random

I researched over the internet, but could not find anything...

I have a mysql db, and records at a table, and I need to get random record from this table at every page load. how can I do that? Is there any func for that?

Appreciate! thanks

---

SORTED:
link: http://www.derekallard.com/blog/post/ordering-database-results-by-random-in-codeigniter/

```
$this->db->select('name');
$query = $this->db->get('table');
$shuffled_query = $query->result_array();
shuffle ($shuffled_query);

foreach ($shuffled_query as $row) {
    echo $row['name'] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: $this->db->order_by('rand()'); is the line which you add into your code to get random results

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Codeigniter provides the ability to order your results by 'RANDOM' when you run a query. For instance

```
function get_random_page()
{
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'RANDOM');
    or
    $this->db->order_by('rand()');
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get('pages');
    return $query->result_array();

}
```

I've used this before and found it to work fine.

Comment: for large table, this solution is very slow! best method is generate a random number in php and `SELECT` and `WHERE` in mysql. @RajSar 's method is simular to this.

Comment: @user57750 that's unreliable. What if some of the records were corrupt or had been removed?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know about codeigniter, but getting a random dataset is

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

The relevant part is "`ORDER BY RAND()`", obviously.

Comment: hey thanks, from your clue, I found the link http://www.derekallard.com/blog/post/ordering-database-results-by-random-in-codeigniter/ :) sorted!

Answer (score 4):

Do you know how many records there are in the table? You could do something like this:

```
$count=mysql_exec('select count(*)-1 from some_table');
$count=rand(1,$count);
```

then:

```
select * from
some_Table
limit $count,1
```

Comment: I think this is the best way, but should it be Limit $count, 1 ?

Answer (score 4):

This code snippet worked well for me.

```
$this->db->select('name');
$this->db->order_by('rand()');
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get('<table>'); //<table> is the db table name
return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 3):

Getting random record from large table is very expensive.
*Don't use* `ORDER BY RAND()`.

This is a bad idea, but if you have a small table no problem.
In a huge databases this type of queries very slow.

Answer (score 2):

I use codeigniter with datamapper. This is the code which I use to get a record randomly from table `Advertiser`:

```
 $ad = new Advertiser();
 $ad->limit(3);
 $ad->order_by('id', 'RANDOM');
 $ad->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT product_id, title, description
FROM products
WHERE active = 1
AND stock > 0
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 4
```

The ORDER BY RAND() clause returns random records! You can limit records also using LIMIT.

Answer (score 1):

Lets think we have table where we deleted some rows. There is maybe ID not continues correctly. For sample id: 1,5,24,28,29,30,31,32,33 (9 rows)

mysql_num_rows returns 9

Another methods will return not existing rows:
$count=9; //because mysql_num_rows()==9
$count=rand(1,$count); // returns 4 for sample, but we havn't row with id=4

But with my method you always get existing rows. You can separate code and use first 2 code anywhere on site.

```
// Inside of Controller Class
    function _getReal($id,$name_of_table)
 {
 $Q=$this->db->where('id',$id)->get($name_of_table);
 if($Q->num_rows()>0){return $Q;}else{return FALSE;}
 }

 function _getLastRecord($name_of_table)
 {
 $Q=$this->db->select("id")->order_by('id DESC')->limit("1")->get($name_of_table)->row_array();
 return $Q['id'];
 }

 function getrandom()
 {
       $name_of_table="news";
 $id=rand(1,$this->_getLastRecord($name_of_table));
 if($this->_getReal($id,$name_of_table)!==FALSE)
 {
         echo $id;
         // Here goes your code
 }
 else
 {
         $this->getrandom();
 }
// END
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting random record from large table is very expensive. But bellow this code is very effective ..

```
$count=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from table_name WHERE SOME_OF_YOUR_CONDITION"));
$nums=rand(1,$count);


mysql_query(" select * from table_name WHERE SOME_OF_YOUR_CONDITION LIMIT $count,1");
```

This will be helpful ...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not best way. For sample, you've deleted record which is `now==$count`. You must iterate this for `mysql_num_rows()`

Answer (score 0):

This function retrieve all rows in table in random order

```
public function get_questions(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->order_by('rand()');
    $this->db->from('multiple_choices');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Random row without ORDER BY RAND() query:

```
$all_rows = $this->db->get('table')->result_array();
$random_row = $all_rows[rand(0,count($all_rows)-1)];
```