# How to get random row from MYSQL and how to write it in active records?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

This is my query

```
"SELECT * FROM package_info ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,3;"
```

I try to write it in active records like this.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('package_info');
$this->db->order_by("id", "random");
$this->db->limit(0, 3);
$result = $this->db->get();
```

But it is not work. How to write this in active record?

Comment: `$this->db->order_by('rand()');` Instead, as your `order_by( "id" .. )` won't match your first query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random record from mysql database with CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627934/random-record-from-mysql-database-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Below code it will work fine -

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('package_info');
$this->db->order_by("id", "random");
$this->db->limit(3, 0);
$result = $this->db->get()->result(); 

// shows last executed query
echo $this->db->last_query();

// shows data fetched
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

You can visit on this link to view how queries are used in Codeigniter.
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter does not mandate that you provide 2 arguments for most Query Builder statements, you can do a whole WHERE  by doing `->where('1=1')` and its perfectly fine.

I'm surprised how many people don't understand method chaining, but I'll show it in my example it is just nicer...

```
$result = $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('package_info')
    ->order_by('rand()')
    ->limit(0, 3)
    >get();
```

As per above, if you don't have 2 parameters in your original query, dont feel compelled to add two.

Another thing you can do with basic queries like these, is omit the `from('package_info')` entirely and stick the table name in the `->get('package_info')`

If you cant be bothered with query builder you don't need to use it either. I don't for some things (you cannot use UNION with them for one). In this case just use

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM package_info ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,3;");
```

Comment: Looks like OP's issue was the `limit()`, not the `order_by`! Secondly, the accepted answer uses CI2 Docs! :/ Alas.

Comment: When someone gives a plain query you assume it is exactly what they want and tested it... oh dear...